# Update object with value of array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For a project where we have actions and donations. We store the donations in an array in the related action. For the connection we use Mongoose.

The schema for an action is as follows, for readability I've removed some fields which are not related to this problem:

```js
const donationSchema = new Schema(
  {
    id: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
      index: true,
    },
    amount: { type: Number },
    status: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['pending', 'collected', 'failed'],
      default: 'pending',
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true, versionKey: false, _id: false },
);

const schema = new Schema(
  {
    donations: { type: [donationSchema], default: [] },
    target: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    collected: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
  },
);
const Action = model<IAction>('Action', schema);
```

Let say I have an Action with three donations, one in every state:

```json
{
  "_id": "6098fb22101f22cfcbd31e3b"
  "target": 10000,
  "collected": 25,
  "donations": [
    {
      "uuid": "dd90f6f1-56d7-4d8b-a51f-f9e5382d3cd9",
      "amount": 25,
      "status": "collected"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "eea0ac5e-1e52-4eba-aa1f-c1f4d072a37a",
      "amount": 10,
      "status": "failed"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "215237bd-bfe6-4d5a-934f-90e3ec9d2aa1",
      "amount": 50,
      "status": "pending"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to update the pending donation to `collected`.

This would be

```js
Action.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: '6098fb22101f22cfcbd31e3b',
    'donations.id': '215237bd-bfe6-4d5a-934f-90e3ec9d2aa1',
  },
  {
    $set: {
      'donations.$.status': 'collected',
    },
  },
  {
    upsert: false,
    returnOriginal: false,
  }
).then((action) => console.log(action);
```

I want to update the status to collected, but also update the `collected` so that it is the same as all the donations with `status` equal to `collected`. I thought of using the [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator, but this keeps saying that `donations.$.amount` is not a number and therefore not able to increment `collected`.

Is there a way to do this in the same update call? The reason why I cannot get the object and just count collected amount is that maybe two donation callbacks occur at the same time, so we don't want the to overwrite the previous given amount.

Answer (score 1):

This aggregation can help you I believe:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      _id: "6098fb22101f22cfcbd31e3b"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "donations.status": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$donations",
          "initialValue": {
            uuid: "215237bd-bfe6-4d5a-934f-90e3ec9d2aa1"
          },
          "in": {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.uuid",
                  "$$value.uuid"
                ]
              },
              "collected",
              "$$this.status"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "collected": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$donations",
          "initialValue": "$collected",
          "in": {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.status",
                  "collected"
                ]
              },
              {
                $sum: [
                  "$$value",
                  "$$this.amount"
                ]
              },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Edit: Above aggregation wasn't properly update `status` field to "collected" dunno why..

But `update` query below should work. I couldn't test it too. So, please let me know if something goes wrong.

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "6098fb22101f22cfcbd31e3b"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "donations.$[element].status": "collected",
    "$inc": {
      "donations.$[element].amount": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "donations.$[element].status",
              "collected"
            ]
          },
          "donations.$[element].amount",
          "collected"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "element.uuid": "215237bd-bfe6-4d5a-934f-90e3ec9d2aa1"
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. When I log the result of the aggregation, I do get the object I want, so the `$match` step works, but the collected stayed on `25` and the state didn't get changed to `collected`. Another thing was that when I changed some names around, I still didn't get new (not correctly filled) fields to save. To the DB even though they were logged.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't test though. I'll check this

Comment: @Bas I updated my answer. Please let me know if it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This one works beter, the status of the donation is updating correctly, but the `collected` field on Action is not updating. This stays on 25. After reading more into it, I'm thinking that `$set` and `$inc` should be separate properties, but not sure.

Comment: What I currently do as temporary solution, is getting the donation object, and then just use `{$set: {"donations.$.status": "collected"}, $inc: {'collected': "THE_AMOUNT_HERE" }}` as update object. If you know a way to not get the donationObject at first, that'd be great. Also, when I'm thinking more of it, a recount every time might be beter then a increment, seeing that I could send the same call twice.

Comment: Wow, I was so sure about the second solution.. Maybe you can try to split the second solution into two different queries. So one will be `$set -> "donations.$[element].status": "collected"....` Other will be `$set -> "$inc": {
      "donations.$[....`

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem. I think that for now, I'll keep my temp solution and look further into it when I have more time available. But thanks for all the help!